# Get Success Value from ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have following response from my ajax request

```
response: {
 Success : false;
 Success Message: '';
 ErrorMessage: 'Test';
}
```

I want to get Success value in console.log but I am not able to get this.

I am getting response text like this.

```
var o = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
console.log(o);
```

This gives me entire response in console, but when I try to get success message only like this.

```
console.log(o.Success);
```

It give me undefined. Anyone please identify what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This is invalid JSON.

Comment: Use https://jsonlint.com site to validate json

Comment: you have empty space `Success :` change it to `Success:` or access like `console.log(o['Success '])`

Answer (score 0):

JSON fields should be separated by comma, not by a semicolumn. I'm guessing thats why parseJSON doesn't convert it properly.